# BufferedReader: read multiple lines into a single string

Tags: java, text-processing, bufferedreader

I'm reading numbers from a txt file using BufferedReader for analysis. The way I'm going about this now is- reading a line using .readline, splitting this string into an array of strings using .split

```
public InputFile () {
    fileIn = null;

    //stuff here

    fileIn = new FileReader((filename + ".txt"));
    buffIn = new BufferedReader(fileIn);


    return;
    //stuff here
}
```

---

```
public String ReadBigStringIn() {
    String line = null;

    try { line = buffIn.readLine(); }
    catch(IOException e){};

    return line;
}
```

---

```
public ProcessMain() {
    initComponents();
    String[] stringArray;
    String line;

    try {
        InputFile stringIn = new InputFile();
        line = stringIn.ReadBigStringIn();
        stringArray = line.split("[^0-9.+Ee-]+"); 
        // analysis etc.
    }
}
```

This works fine, but what if the txt file has multiple lines of text? Is there a way to output a single long string, or perhaps another way of doing it? Maybe use `while(buffIn.readline != null) {}`? Not sure how to implement this.

Ideas appreciated,
thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are right, a loop would be needed here.

The usual idiom (using only plain Java) is something like this:

```
public String ReadBigStringIn(BufferedReader buffIn) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder everything = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while( (line = buffIn.readLine()) != null) {
       everything.append(line);
    }
    return everything.toString();
}
```

This removes the line breaks - if you want to retain them, don't use the `readLine()` method, but simply read into a `char[]` instead (and append this to your StringBuilder).

Please note that this loop will run until the stream ends (and will block if it doesn't end), so if you need a different condition to finish the loop, implement it in there.

Comment: The bad thing on this is that you cant use it on servers as they are endless waiting for readLine()

Comment: @Niton how are servers waiting endlessly? readLine will wait endlessly if it tries to read from an open stream without end, but this is not specific to servers.

Comment: Yes but server streams (Socket streams) do only end when they are closed so on servers its better to use a "end of the message condition". (for example the blank line in the end of an HTTP request to keep the stream open but tell the client that the request is done)

Comment: Your answer is rigth but sadly for me not useable for servers/protocols.
But nervermind i have a solution, only wanted to point it out

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly advice using library here but since Java 8 you can do this also using streams.

```
    try (InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
         BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(in)) {
        final String fileAsText = buffer.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println(fileAsText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can notice also that it is pretty effective as `joining` is using `StringBuilder` internally.

Comment: That's a great oneliner, instead of having to iterate the buffer, check null, tostring etc.

Comment: If you want to preserve the line endings, you may add System.lineSeparator() as a paramenter for Collectors.joining: buffer.lines().collect( Collectors.joining( System.lineSeparator() ) )

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to read the entirety of a file into a string, I suggest you use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)'s [`Files`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) class:

```
String text = Files.toString("filename.txt", Charsets.UTF_8);
```

Of course, that's assuming you want to maintain the linebreaks. If you want to remove the linebreaks, you could either load it that way and then use String.replace, or you could use Guava again:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readLines(new File("filename.txt"), Charsets.UTF_8);
String joined = Joiner.on("").join(lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want Apache IO FileUtils

```
String text = FileUtils.readStringFromFile(new File(filename + ".txt"));
String[] stringArray = text.split("[^0-9.+Ee-]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `StringBuilder`, then you can append every line to it, and return the String using `toString()` at the end.

You can replace your ReadBigStringIn() with

```
public String ReadBigStringIn() {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            String line = buffIn.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                b.append(line);
                line = buffIn.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){};

        return b.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates a long string, every line is seprateted from string " " (one space):

```
public String ReadBigStringIn() {
    StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();


    try { 
        while(buffIn.ready()) {
        line.append(" " + buffIn.readLine());
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return line.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a file containing doubles. Looks like you have more than one number per line, and may have multiple lines.

Simplest thing to do is read lines in a while loop.

You could return null from your ReadBigStringIn method when last line is reached and terminate your loop there.

But more normal would be to create and use the reader in one method. Perhaps you could change to a method which reads the file and returns an array or list of doubles.

BTW, could you simply split your strings by whitespace?

Reading a whole file into a single String may suit your particular case, but be aware that it could cause a memory explosion if your file was very large. Streaming approach is generally safer for such i/o.