# how to take inputs seperated by new line

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an input with the line breaks. I want to convert that string into an array, and for every new line, jump one index place in the array.

If the input is:

> 100
>   200
>   300

Then I need the output to be:

> 110
>   210
>   310

I have used the following code:

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str=br.readLine();
        String [] arrOfStr = str.split("\n");int b=0;
        for (String a : arrOfStr) {
            b=Integer.parseInt(a);
            int c=b+10;
            System.out.println(c);
        }
     }
}
```

But it is not giving the desired output.
*Note*: We are not taking the input from text file. We don't know how many inputs are there in test case. We have take inputs in one go.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: @dbf Yes, but it is taking only one input at a time.

Comment: Use str.split("\r\n") There's a whole thread about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line

Comment: @Waffles I am only getting 110. not 210 and 310 in output

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the problem you're having... br.readLine() only reads ONE line. If you want it to read after line breaks you'll have to implement a while loop. str.split won't work for this case. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5516075/3072960

Comment: you should use loop for reading from your file and then in while block you must use br.readline for reading each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment.

```
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str = br.readLine();
    while (!str.isEmpty()) {
        intList.add(Integer.parseInt(str)+10);
        str=br.readLine();

    }
    System.out.println(intList);}
```

This should work, I'm on my phone...

Comment: `readLine()` will return `null` at the end of file, not an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `scanner.hasNext()` instead as -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // scanner.useDelimiter("\\r\\n"); // if required to delimit the input 
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        int c = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next()) + 10;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Using the same Input as yours -

> ```
> 100
> 200
> 300
> ```

The Output would be -

> ```
> 110
> 210
> 310
> ```